# Why is Windows Restarting my Service which I've Manually Stopped?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-service

We have three servers - Windows 2012 R2 - in Azure, running a variety of our own custom developed services. These services are configured to start automatically, so naturally, on startup or after a reboot we expect to find these services running.

Occasionally, we need to stop these services in order to upgrade our application. When we stop these services we want them to stay stopped until we are ready to restart them again. We're finding though, that approximately one hour after the services are stopped they restart spontaneously, to all appearances.

Now obviously, the term "spontaneously" is a bit of hyperbole; "something" is restarting these, but I'm at a loss to pinpoint this trigger. Is there a feature of Windows Server, or perhaps a Domain Policy for these servers, which periodically restarts any service which is marked as Automatic Start but is found not to be running? I've never heard of this. None of these services have any Recovery options defined, but in any case isn't that irrelevant? These services did not "crash", they were terminated cleanly by an explicit Stop command. There are no external dependencies which would cause these services to start automatically, except of course an OS restart, which is not happening in these instances.

I stopped a service, did a gpupdate /force and the service did not restart. I think this is an indication that this is not restarting based on group policy, because if so, I'd have expected the gpupdate to trigger the restart. (But I'm not an expert in this area so I could be wrong about this.)

Thanks for any advice which you can offer.

Comment: I've never seen or even heard or native Windows functionality that would do this. I have seen plenty of third party products that do it. I recommend starting there, possibly the AWS monitoring products. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-monitor-windows-and-linux-servers-and-get-internal-performance-metrics/

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks! I'll look into this. In our case it's Azure, but if AWS has this sort of monitoring, chances are that Azure has something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT due to Windows behavior. I found out from our Cloud Services Provider that they have their own automation tool which monitors for stopped services and restarts them. I've instructed them - stop doing that!

I'll leave this post up because I've seen other admins (not a lot, but several) asking the same question. My advice, as per the comment above, and per my own experience is to look elsewhere as this behavior is not likely to be rooted in the native Windows service management.